# How do I display the Gender difference with 2 colors in my boxplot?

Tags: seaborn, boxplot

I'm trying to plot 2 categorical variables and 1 numerical variable in different boxplots using FacetGrid.I need the color differentiation for Genders in the boxplots.

Following code I tried:

box_gender_order= pisa['Gender'].value_counts().index
g = sb.FacetGrid(data = pisa, col = 'Country', height = 3, col_order= high_math_score.head(3).index,palette= sb.color_palette(['blue','orange']),
                 col_wrap= 3, margin_titles = True)
g.map(sb.boxplot, 'Gender', 'Avg Math Score', order= box_gender_order);

The box plots do not show any difference in color though I see them well plotted.

Comment: Please let me know if any of need any more information. Would greatly appreciate any help.